# how to print " * " n number of times using while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class Hello {

    public static void pattern() {
        int s1 = 3;

        while(s1 >= 1) {
            System.out.println("*");
            s1--;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        pattern();
    }

}
```

Actual output:

```
*
*
*
```

Expected output:

```
* * *
 * *
  *
```

I would like to print " * " (like the above-expected output) using while loop. I made a while loop controlling the number of columns. I'm not able to make a while loop to control the rows to output "*" in the same line 3 times (next line 2 times and so on).

Comment: You need <two while loops> or <a while loop and a for loop>.

Comment: println() always makes a new Line. Try the print() method instead

Comment: @Naetmul What should be the condition for the second while loop?

Comment: `for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {System.out.println(" ".repeat(3 - i) + "* ".repeat(i));}`

Comment: @SashrikR The outer loop is for each line. The inner loop is for each star.

Comment: String.repeat() can be used in Java 11 and afterward. I don't know the OP's environment.

Answer (score 2):

With just you one loop and some `String.repeat()` you can draw your pattern

- Repeat the leading space, starting and 0, and one more each round
- Repeat the pattern  depending ong `s1`, 3 times, then 2 then 1

```
public static void pattern() {
    int s1 = 3;
    int s2 = 0; // space counter
    while(s1 >= 1) {
        System.out.print(" ".repeat(s2));
        System.out.println("* ".repeat(s1).trim()); // trim to remove last space
        s1--;
        s2++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sidenote that `String.repeat(int)` is only available from Java 11 onwards

Comment: @azro what does repeat do?

Comment: @SashrikR have you just googled it ? You would have find the documentation first result. It repeats the string the given amount of time `"ab".repeat(3) => ababab `

Answer (score 0):

```
int lines = 0, asterisks = 3;
String whiteSpace = "";
while (lines++ < 3) {
    System.out.print(whiteSpace);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i <= (asterisks - lines)) {
            System.out.print("* ");
        }
    }
    whiteSpace += " ";
    System.out.println();
}
```