# How to output " * " with the necessary spacing and indents with while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
public class Hello {

    public static void pattern() {
        s1 = 3;

        while(s1 > 0) {
            int i = s1;
            while(i > 0){
                System.out.print("* ");
                i--;
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
            s1--;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        pattern();
    }

}

Output: 
* * *  
* *  
*  
expected output:
* * *
 * *
  *
```

How do I write my program with the necessary spacing and indents(using a while loop), such that I get the expected output?

Thank you in advance!

(I'm new to StackOverflow, forgive me if my pattern of asking a question is not right)

Comment: Add another loop inside your outer loop that will print the required amount of spaces at the start of each line. Find a relation between the expected number of spaces and the line number/your s1 variable

Comment: Surprisingly someone had a similiar problem today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62383448/how-to-print-n-number-of-times-using-while-loop

Comment: The downvotes likely come from the fact that you did little research before asking, as there are many duplicates on this website. Also, you did not explain what is unclear to you, you have to tell us what exactly is confusing you and where you are stuck. Posting your attempt without any explanation of what you do not get regarding the next steps is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
public static void pattern() {
        int s1 = 3;

        for(int i= 0; i<=s1-1; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<=i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for(int k=0; k<=s1-1-i; k++)
            {
                System.out.print("*" + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

1. `Outer for-loop` is used to maintain `row` i.e. `3`.
2. `Inner for-loop` is used to maintain `column` i.e. `for(int k=0; k<=s1-1-i; k++)`.
3. `for (int j=0; j<=i; j++)` is used to maintain `spaces` corresponsding to each row start.